# Core dumped when running C program

Tags: c

I create a C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void user_connect( char user[], char date[]){
FILE* fichier=NULL;
fichier=fopen("log.txt","+a");
fprintf(fichier,"user:%s connected at :%s",user,date);
fclose(fichier);

}

void etat_periph( char periph[]){

FILE* fichier=NULL;
fichier=fopen("log.txt","+a");
fprintf(fichier,periph);
fclose(fichier);

}

int main()
{
    char user[]="user";
    char periph[]="led is on";
    char date[]="02/08/2015";

    user_connect(user,date);
    etat_periph(periph);
    return 0;
}
```

when I run it I got this error message "segmentation fault(core dumped)"
I tried to debugger it but I didn't get any valuable thing to resolve it.

Comment: Side note: Don't do this: `fprintf(fichier,periph);` The string `periph` could contain format specifiers, which will trip up `fprintf`. Use `fprintf(fichier, "%s" periph);` instead

Comment: Also, check the return value of `fopen` to see if it was successful.

Comment: please indent code consistently.  suggest 4 spaces after every opening brace '{' and un-indent before every closing brace '}'  Never use tabs for indenting as every wordprocessor/editor has the tab stops/tab width set for individual needs

Comment: could it be that the file log.txt does not exist or is not accessable from where the executable is being run?  Always check (!=NULL) the returned value from fopen() to assure the operation was successful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should change your code to

```
fichier=fopen("log.txt","a+");
```

"+a" -> "a+"

Comment: Or maybe just `"a"`, because you don't need read access in any of the two cases.

Comment: order does not count in the mode string